# C++/WinRT Library support

Tags: c++-winrt

Does c++/WinRT supports c++ static/dynamic library?

I have a c++ static library which I tried to add as a reference in c++/winrt project but VS says project not supported!

My VS Version :: **Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019
Version 16.4.5**

How I tried to add reference :

- Right click on my project-> Add->Reference
- Select the c++ library project from the Add Reference window

Then a warning dialog is shown that project is not supported. Please see the attached image

[image]

Comment: This is asking the wrong question. C++/WinRT doesn't place any restrictions on your application. It's just a header-only library after all. It's not clear from the question, how you tried to *"add [...] a reference"* to your static library, but it sounds like that's where you went wrong. A static library is added as an additional input to the linker.

Comment: @IInspectable I added more information. Please see the edit. Why do you say it's a wrong question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?view=vs-2019), it mentions

> If you just try to add a reference from a Universal Windows Project to
>   a classic desktop library, you get an error message that says the
>   library is not compatible. In the case of a static library, you can
>   link to your library simply by adding the library (.lib file) to your
>   linker input.

Do not add a reference in the References node in Solution Explorer. That mechanism only works for Windows Runtime Components.

So you need to right-click your c++/winrt project, choose C**onfiguration Properties > Linker > Input** and add the path to the library in the **Additional Dependencies**. Then include the header file to your pch.h or .cpp file.

The specific steps you can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?view=vs-2019#to-use-a-native-c-static-library-in-a-uwp-project).